# What is preferred: Pagerule or 'Always use Https'?

Tags: cloudflare

I want to ensure that all traffic coming to my servers (including a wordpress server and others hosted on Google comopute) via Cloudflare are https only.

At the moment I used this page rule:

[image]

Then I realised there is this option:

[image]

Which is the more preferred method to achieve the goal (for example in term of performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about performance with either, because both are documented and supported methods and serving HTTPS consumes more resources than any redirect on HTTP anyway. Your goal is to *ensure that all traffic is https only*. With *HTTP Strict Transport Security* (HSTS, [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)) you can ensure that. There's also difference in performance as the URLs are rewritten client side.

Cloudflare blog [How to make your site HTTPS-only](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-make-your-site-https-only/) suggests using the *HTTPS-only* feature and suggests HSTS as the next step. A [blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/enforce-web-policy-with-hypertext-strict-transport-security-hsts/) from when HSTS was first introduced in Cloudflare beta dashboard explains this more thoroughly and also warns it's more permanent than redirecting:

> There is one caveat to HSTS: it's a policy cached in each browser. If
> you configure HSTS settings, browsers will cache those settings for
> the duration of max-age. We recommend 6 months. If your site becomes
> inaccessible over strongly-configured HTTPS, web browsers will refuse
> to connect to the site on HTTP until the policy expires in the
> browser. Therefore, it's important that you set up HSTS only after
> establishing a stable SSL configuration. Fortunately, CloudFlare's
> default SSL settings are perfectly compatible with HSTS.